# Handle Dynamic boundary in Jmeter

Tags: performance-testing

ab&2e;1652769179"/>
i did correlction using rerular expression ab&2e;(.*?)"/>

but during execution some times extra text (cd&3d;) adding to the data like

ab&2e;cd&3d;1652769179"/>

So need to ignore data "cd&3d;"

Please let me know any idea to ignore text cd&3d;
Thanks

Thanks
Raghav

Comment: I think I have answered your question in the post I marked as duplicate, either this or the other one should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which returns the above response
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `boundary`
   - Regular Expression: `_-(\d+)"/>`
   - Template: `$1$`

     [image]
3. That's it, you should be able to access the extracted value as `${boundary}` where required

Be aware that you can test your regular expressions using [RegExp Tester mode of the View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)

[image]