# Left boundary test Text ignore in Regular expression in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

ab&2e;1652769179"/>

i did correlction using rerular expression ab&2e;(.*?)"/>

but during execution some times extra text (cd&3d;) adding to the data like

ab&2e;cd&3d;1652769179"/>

So need to ignore data "cd&3d;"

Please let me know **any idea to ignore text cd&3d;** and capture 1652769179 only using expresiion ab&2e;(.*?)"/>

Thanks
Raghav

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle Dynamic boundary in Jmeter](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41203/handle-dynamic-boundary-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 1):

If the extra text is always "cd&3d" something like this will help:

```
ab&2e;(?:cd&3d;)*(.*?)"\/>
```

where `(?:)` is a **non-capturing group** and `*` is for **0 or more** matches.

I would also change the `(.*?)` to `(.\d?)` if its always **digits** you are dealing with.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

When the Left boundary is dynamic and you want just to capture the numbers in the response, try using

```
\w+[\x21-\x2F]\w+;(?:.*?;)*(.\d+)"\/>
```

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/o3fjP7/1)

This will group the numbers.